# How to append text to line d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

In this fiddle I'm attempting to draw line and label it with text :

http://jsfiddle.net/96QSs/33/

fiddle code :

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width" , 300)
    .attr("height" , 300);

var labelLine = svg.append("line")
                .attr("x1", 10)
                .attr("y1", 20)
                .attr("x2", 10)
                .attr("y2", 30)
                .attr("stroke-width", 2);

    labelLine.append("text")
        .attr("dx", 12)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return "test" });
```

But no line or text is being drawn. Should this line with text not be drawn ?

Comment: "Should this line with text not be drawn?" is that a philosophical question? Works for me when appending the text to the right element and adding some CSS for the line to be shown http://jsfiddle.net/96QSs/34/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff ah, I appended to label instead of svg element, thanks its being drawn now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append text to a line in d3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723541/how-to-append-text-to-a-line-in-d3-js)